# Changing the name of the method called dynamically in java

Tags: java, methods, dynamic

I have an object "JudgesSubmission" with the following methods:

```
public String getInnovationGrade1() {
    return innovationGrade1;
}
public String getInnovationGrade2() {
    return innovationGrade2;
}
public String getInnovationGrade3() {
    return innovationGrade3;
}
public String getInnovationGrade4() {
    return innovationGrade4;
}
```

Now, when calling these methods, I want to put them in a loop where the called method name gets the index of the loop attached to its end changing the method called. Is this possible?
For example, the following code would never work, but I am writing it to explain what I need:

```
judgesSubmission metricScores= new judgesSubmission;
int metricSum=0;
for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
metricSum=metricSum
      Integer.parseInt(metricScores.getInnovationGrade+"i"());
}
```

Is there a way to do that or do I always have the full method name written?

Comment: Why not just hold an array/collection in your class? Why four different methods?

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is not possible... but with reflection such as :

```
MyObject.class.getMethod("mymethod"+i);
```

Without reflection you could use a `Supplier<String>` :

```
public void process(Supplier<String>... suppliers){

    judgesSubmission metricScores= new judgesSubmission;
    int metricSum=0;
    for (Supplier<String> supplier : suppliers){
          Integer.parseInt(supplier.get());
    }
}
```

And call it such as :

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
process(()->myObject.getInnovationGrade1(), 
    ()->myObject.getInnovationGrade2(),
    ()->myObject.getInnovationGrade3(),
    ()->myObject.getInnovationGrade4());
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible without [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) (and is highly not recommended)

Instead you may want to use other methods:

1. An array of the data (either replacing the 4 methods, or in addition)

   ```
   String[] getInnovationGrades()
   {
       return new String[]{innovationGrade1, innovationGrade2, innovationGrade3, innovationGrade4};
   }
   ```

   - Then later you can use

     ```
     for(String innovationGrade : getInnovationGrades())
         //do stuff
     ```
2. An argument to get the data you want

   ```
   String getInnovationGrade(int i)
   {
       switch(i)
       {
           case 1:
               return getInnovationGrade1();
           case 2:
               return getInnovationGrade2();
           case 3:
               return getInnovationGrade3();
           case 4:
               return getInnovationGrade4();
           default:
               return ""; //or throw exception, depends on how you wish to handle errors
       }
   }
   ```

   - Then later you can use

     ```
     for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
         getInnovationGrade(i); //and do stuff with it
     ```

Comment: This way is not so bad (+1). But it has still a drawback : you have to maintain both client and service side as you add or remove a method.

Comment: Even without full access to both parts of the code, an adapter/wrapper wouldn't be a terrible idea to implement

Comment: Really sure. But by using `Supplier`, you don't have this maintenance drawback.